# Spring AOP transaction management for service layer

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-aop

I refer to the example stated in the URL which is to apply spring aop transaction across all methods in service layers, but this will also apply transaction management for read-only methods like SELECT.

Is there any adverse effect, if I apply transaction management for readOnly transaction?

```
<aop:config>
<aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.xyz.someapp.service.*.*(..)))"
advice-ref="transactionAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-declarative-transactions.jsp

I have another question. If I have orderService.create() which invokes billingService.create(), how will the transaction isolation be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally *want* to use transactions even for read-only operations, since a transaction will give you a consistent view of your data. If you skip transactions, you risk seeing partial updates from some other incomplete transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't think that there will be any adverse effects because a transaction simply defines an atomic set of operations. If a transaction fails then a rollback will be performed, but read-only operations don't affect the database in any way.
The only big disadvantage I can think of is related to performance. The locking-strategy of the underlying database (whether table or row is locked) determines your isolation level. Acoording to your locking-strategy some kind of isolation is applied during the transaction. For example, when you're writing to a database your isolation level decides if the changes in progress could be seen by parallel reads (causing e.g. dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and so on) or if these changes have to be commited before they become visible to others.
 As a consequence you would lock resources you only want to read, which could be performance overkill on highly available applications. Summing up: It doesn't have bad effects aside from causing performance issues.

Addressing your second question: This depends on how you're managing transactions. I guess in this case both service methods require transactions, so I think the default behavior is that the transaction of the first service call is inherited by the second service method call (this is called 'transaction propagation'). This is required because nested transactions aren't allowed.